# Use CSS (and maybe JavaScript) to make an element be square (or maintain a specific aspect ratio)

Tags: javascript, css, resize

I have a div that I want to have the following characteristics:

- Width = 50% of its parent element
- Height equal to whatever it needs to be in order to maintain a certain aspect ratio.

I need to use percentages because the object will resize left-right when the browser is resized. I want the object to be resized top-bottom to ensure the object maintains the same aspect ratio.

I don't think there's any way to use pure CSS to do this, but does anyone know of a way? Alternatively, is there an easy JavaScript way to do this? (JQuery is fine.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out how to do this without js, though you need to use a transparent image.

Set up a html structure like:

```
<div class="rect_container"><img class="rect_image" src="rect_image.png"/>
 <div class="rect">Your favorite content here</div>
</div>
```

Use a AxB transparent png for rect_image where AxB is the aspect ratio.

Meanwhile set up a stylesheet like:

```
.rect_container {width: 50%; position: relative;}
.rect_image {width: 100%; display: block;}
.rect {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
```

The important thing here is taking advantage of the fact that images maintain their aspect ratio when resized in one direction.  Meanwhile, we need a useable div, so we make the image display as block, wrap it in a div, and put an absolutely positioned div inside that. I distilled this code from something more complicated I actually tested.  Works like a charm.

Comment: Pretty genius. I love it when JS isn't needed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure CSS version with no img tag:

```
<div class="apple_container"><div class="apple_icon"></div></div>
```

SCSS (include Compass to render the background-size):

```
.apple_container {
  width: 50%;
}
.apple_icon {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-image: url(/images/apple.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  @include background-size(contain);
  background-position: center center;
}
```

CSS generated from the above:

```
.apple_container {
  width: 50%;
}
.apple_icon {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-image: url(/images/apple.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Results in a square element with a background image centered and fitted within it. This is good for responsive elements that you want to resize dependent on the user's device.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery sounds pretty easy. Set the 50% width in the CSS, and then the following:

```
function onResize() {
    var el = $('#element');
    el.height(el.width());
}
$(window).resize(onResize);
$(document).ready(onResize);
```

Comment: Still holding out for some clever, pure CSS answer but otherwise I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: I think for images you can do height: auto, but only for images.

Comment: Bummer. I need to do this for a div containing a flash element.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [Detecting a browser resize using JQuery](http://snipplr.com/view/9097/jquery-detecting-a-browser-resize/).