# Setting height to width

Tags: css

Lets say i have a div

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 447px;
  height: 447px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 1.3%;
  margin-top: 1.3%;
  max-width: 23.4%;
  max-height: 47%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The div is box-shaped , it has same width and height.
But as the browser keep resizing and screen getting smaller due to max-width and max-height set to % value i wont have to use media queries but the ratio between
width and height gets more and more different.
So lets say the screen size is 1440x900 , the calculation of width and height will be different and box shape will get destroyed to rectangle.

Is there a way how to keep the div box shaped without using extra mediaqueries?

Comment: [Google box square css or so](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/14/css-responsive-square/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **viewport units** and set `height` and `width` to same `vw` for example.

```css
div{
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Too keep square inside screen boundaries you can add `max-height` and `max-width` in `vh` units

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div{
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That will keep it square, but not within the screen boundaries if that would be necessary.

Comment: You can always use `40vmin` if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Viewport unit options are almost universally supported at this point.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

However, you could also use [javascript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2066114/188963).

```
function onResize() {
    var el = $('#element');
    el.height(el.width());
}
$(window).resize(onResize);
$(document).ready(onResize);
```

Note, your question is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
div+div { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div></div><div></div>
```

Comment: in a scenario , where multiple divs are in the row , it destroys the whole positioning.

Comment: @trolkura I'm not sure what you mean by destroying the positioning.  It works exactly how it is supposed to.  If you want them side by side, then use `display: inline-block`.  Updated answer to show that.